# Survival analysis using cox returns "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

Tags: python, pandas, series, valueerror, cox-regression

So I'm working with a dataset of Stroke cases from an hospital, and I would like to use Cox regression to make a survival analysis using time of arrival in the hospital, time of leave and survival or not. I have also lab data, sex, and age of the patient. processing the data is pretty straight forward but the I'm trying to use lifelines CoxPHFitter and fit it to the data I get the error : "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
I will paste down here some info about the data I'm using :

```
X.info()
X.head()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4552 entries, 0 to 4551
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   CHOL    4552 non-null   float64
 1   sex     4552 non-null   int64  
 2   age     4552 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2)
```

|  | CHOL | Sex | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4.9 | 1 | 95 |
| 1 | 4.9 | 1 | 91 |
| 2 | 4.1 | 0 | 50 |
| 3 | 5.6 | 0 | 79 |
| 4 | 4.9 | 0 | 57 |

I use T and E as:

```
T = df['survival_time']  # Time-to-event data
E = df['event_occurred']  # Censoring indicator
```

where T is leave date of the hospital - admission to the hospital date in days
and E is 1 for Death as a result or 0 for survival (also tried True and False)

And this is how I use the CoxPHfitter :

```
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter

# Fit Cox proportional hazards model
coxph = CoxPHFitter()
coxph.fit(X, duration_col=T, event_col=E)

print(coxph.summary())
```

The line `coxph.fit(X, duration_col=T, event_col=E)` generates this error : `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Anyone has an idea of why I get this error ?

full error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[150], line 5
      3 # Fit Cox proportional hazards model
      4 coxph = CoxPHFitter()
----> 5 coxph.fit(X, duration_col=T, event_col=E)
      7 print(coxph.summary())

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lifelines/utils/__init__.py:56, in CensoringType.right_censoring.<locals>.f(model, *args, **kwargs)
     53 @wraps(function)
     54 def f(model, *args, **kwargs):
     55     cls.set_censoring_type(model, cls.RIGHT)
---> 56     return function(model, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py:290, in CoxPHFitter.fit(self, df, duration_col, event_col, show_progress, initial_point, strata, weights_col, cluster_col, robust, batch_mode, timeline, formula, entry_col, fit_options)
    184 """
    185 Fit the Cox proportional hazard model to a right-censored dataset. Alias of `fit_right_censoring`.
    186 
   (...)
    287 
    288 """
    289 self.strata = utils._to_list_or_singleton(utils.coalesce(strata, self.strata))
--> 290 self._model = self._fit_model(
    291     df,
    292     duration_col,
    293     event_col=event_col,
    294     show_progress=show_progress,
    295     initial_point=initial_point,
    296     strata=self.strata,
    297     weights_col=weights_col,
    298     cluster_col=cluster_col,
    299     robust=robust,
    300     batch_mode=batch_mode,
    301     timeline=timeline,
    302     formula=formula,
    303     entry_col=entry_col,
    304     fit_options=fit_options,
    305 )
    306 return self

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py:610, in CoxPHFitter._fit_model(self, *args, **kwargs)
    608 def _fit_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
    609     if self.baseline_estimation_method == "breslow":
--> 610         return self._fit_model_breslow(*args, **kwargs)
    611     elif self.baseline_estimation_method == "spline":
    612         return self._fit_model_spline(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py:623, in CoxPHFitter._fit_model_breslow(self, *args, **kwargs)
    619 model = SemiParametricPHFitter(
    620     penalizer=self.penalizer, l1_ratio=self.l1_ratio, strata=self.strata, alpha=self.alpha, label=self._label
    621 )
    622 if utils.CensoringType.is_right_censoring(self):
--> 623     model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
    624     return model
    625 else:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lifelines/utils/__init__.py:56, in CensoringType.right_censoring.<locals>.f(model, *args, **kwargs)
     53 @wraps(function)
     54 def f(model, *args, **kwargs):
     55     cls.set_censoring_type(model, cls.RIGHT)
---> 56     return function(model, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py:1229, in SemiParametricPHFitter.fit(self, df, duration_col, event_col, show_progress, initial_point, strata, weights_col, cluster_col, robust, batch_mode, timeline, formula, entry_col, fit_options)
   1226 self.formula = formula
   1227 self.entry_col = entry_col
-> 1229 X, T, E, weights, entries, original_index, self._clusters = self._preprocess_dataframe(df)
   1231 self.durations = T.copy()
   1232 self.event_observed = E.copy()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py:1305, in SemiParametricPHFitter._preprocess_dataframe(self, df)
   1303     df = df.set_index(self.strata)
   1304 else:
-> 1305     sort_by = [self.duration_col, self.event_col] if self.event_col else [self.duration_col]
   1306     df = df.sort_values(by=sort_by)
   1307     original_index = df.index.copy()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1527, in NDFrame.__nonzero__(self)
   1525 @final
   1526 def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527     raise ValueError(
   1528         f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529         "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1530     )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Can you include the full text of the error traceback? This suggests that the `fit` function is incorrectly using the shorthand (for example) `if s` to test whether a Pandas series `s` is empty or not, but if you're supplying the right types of input then that suggests that someone needs to update the package that that function came from.

Comment: @LucyJanssens try `T.values` and `E.values`

Comment: OK, I had a quick look at the `lifelines` library and it seems up-to-date and well maintained so it's probably that you need to change how you pass the data to it - try what @TinoD suggests and if that doesn't work I suggest seeking further help from the package author or any user community for that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `fit` method of the `CoxPHFitter` class, it expects the datato include all necessary columns like CHOL, sex, and age) as well as the duration and event indicator columns.You are not doing this. you can solve it this way:

```
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'CHOL': [4.9, 4.9, 4.1, 5.6, 4.9],
    'sex': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],  
    'age': [95, 91, 50, 79, 57],
    'survival_time': [20, 40, 15, 10, 30], 
    'event_occurred': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
coxph = CoxPHFitter()
coxph.fit(df, duration_col='survival_time', event_col='event_occurred')
summary = coxph.summary
print(summary)
```

which gives you what you wanted:

```
               coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)  coef lower 95%  coef upper 95%  \
covariate                                                                   
CHOL      -1.067889   0.343734   5.069700      -11.004319        8.868542   
sex       -2.123784   0.119578  15.619846      -32.738120       28.490551   
age        0.059477   1.061282   0.440625       -0.804131        0.923086   

           exp(coef) lower 95%  exp(coef) upper 95%  cmp to         z  \
covariate                                                               
CHOL              1.662972e-05         7.104912e+03     0.0 -0.210641   
sex               6.053620e-15         2.362051e+12     0.0 -0.135967   
age               4.474764e-01         2.517045e+00     0.0  0.134984   

                  p  -log2(p)  
covariate                      
CHOL       0.833167  0.263322  
sex        0.891847  0.165131  
age        0.892625  0.163874
```